# Is the buffer in this function prototype of sprintf() a buffer or just an array whose name happens to be buffer?

Tags: c

The buffer is something that we declare when we write the program just like we declare an array or is it something that's already in the computer.

1. List item

If I declare `char buffer[MAX_LENGTH]`,is the buffer ,which I declare ,a buffer?

1. List item
   Book called Pointers On C says the function sprintf() write values to the buffer.This is the function prototype from the book.`int sprintf(char*buffer,char const * format,...)`Is the buffer in this function prototype a buffer or just an array whose name happens to be buffer?

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char buffer[50]={0};
    sprintf(buffer,"%c%c%c",'a','b','c');
    puts(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is abc.So is the buffer just a ordinary array?Is the buffer here absolutely different with the buffer in I/O?If the buffer here just an ordinary array,then why is the first argument in this function prototype in such a misleading way, instead of just declaring it as char*arr?

Comment: What is a "buffer"?

Comment: zhm, "So is the buffer just a ordinary array?" --> For the most part, yes.

Comment: I/O buffers are simply arrays too, the reason they are called buffers is because you place data in them then the operating system reads them and prints them to screen, they "buffer" the connection between the program and the operating system.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica，So why is the first argument in this function prototype in such a misleading way, instead of just declaring it as char*arr?

Comment: @zhm C spec has `int sprintf(char * restrict s, const char * restrict format, ...);`.  `char*arr` is a slight mis-nomer as `arr` is not an _array_, but a pointer.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica  Passing values from an array to a function is also a pointer.Arrays are the same as Pointers in function prototypes, right?

Comment: Array are not pointers, pointers are not arrays.  An array passed to a function does convert to the address of the first element, yet that is a conversion.  Arrays and pointers remain different.  Consider: `abs(3.14)` converts the `double` to an `int`, yet 3.14 remains a `double`.

Comment: "Arrays are the same as Pointers in function prototypes" There are no arrays in function prototypes (at the top level). `void func(int a[42])` There is no array here. `a` is a pointer. It is written like an array but it is not an array.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes ,but They have the same effect in the declaration of the function prototype like char *arr and arr[].***char*arr is a slight mis-nomer as arr is not an array, but a pointer.***Do you mean char* arr is wrong and I should use char arr[]?

Comment: @zhm Rather that name arguments to redundantly describe the object like `int integer`, `char array[]`, `double floating_point`, use a name that describes it use like `char *buffer`, `char *destination`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`buffer` is nothing more than a chunk of memory used to store the data. So if you store characters - it will be simply a `char` array.

If your data has another type, you will need "a simple" array of that type. Example: jf you want to store `double` you will need array of `double`s

Of course, every array of something is just a chunk of memory.

In declaration:

```
int sprintf(char * restrict s, const char * restrict format, ...);
```

function `sprintf` takes pointers to `char` as parameters, but those pointers simply reference some chunks of memory. You can call them bufferes.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to shed some light on the technical terms. This answer will not be a definition, just the trial to express in simple words, how the terms use commonly used.

---

An "array" is a sequence of elements of identical data type. Its "size" is the number of elements. Some programming languages allow non-negative numbers including zero, but some require at least one element. Commonly the individual elements are accessed by indexes.

"Array" describes only the data type, but not the intended usage.

---

A "buffer" is a specialized space used to, well, buffer values. The reason for buffering depends on the usage, for example a function needs readily available space for generated output.

A buffer can be an array, but it also can be a single value.

"Buffer" does not describe a data type, but an intended usage.

---

The names of parameter shall tell the user the purpose of the parameter. This is true for all names, not only parameter names.

The data type is clear from the specification. It always shows a lack of understanding if a name describes the data type, not the intention.

So, `sprintf(char *buffer, const char *format, ...);` is quite OK.

In contrast, `sprintf(char *arr1, const char *arr2, ...);` brings confusion.